# Check if a form field is empty

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to check if a form field is empty in java. I search a lot, But I only found it in javascript.

The problem is I want to check it in my Controller.

How can I do this?

Regards.

Thank you.

Comment: spring's [validator interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing it in your controller:
`if(request.getParameter().trim().compareTo("") == 0){ // Do what you want`
If you are testing it in your page, simply try this:
`if(field.text.toString().trim().compareTo("") == 0){ //Do what you want`

Comment: I can't accept two responses, but response of Jason is enough for my code. But yours also good.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm seeing Jason's response, and you should know that, sometimes blank does not mean null. If you are testing for real input, try this instead.

Comment: Well, I already known trim, and comparison method, but i forgot, how to get a field. But it's true, your response is more complte.

Answer (score 2):

You can check parameter by HttpServletRequest :

```
    String p = req.getParameter("p");
    if(p==null){
        System.out.println("parameter p is empty");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 6 you can test an empty String :

```
if(null == myString || myString.trim().isEmpty() { .. ;}
```

*EDIT to add trim() for blank removing*

Answer (score 0):

Checking empty filed you have to check null and empty string.

if(str == null && str.equals(""){}